# What space group describes a 1-dimensional crystal with reflection symmetry along axis?

Tags: symmetry, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I'm trying to understand the symmetry of an effectively 1-dimensional system, but I'm confused about how the 1-dimensional ``line groups'' are classified. If you have a system along the $z$-axis which has some periodicity $f(z + na) = f(z)$ for every integer $n$, but also reflection symmetry such that $f(2m - z) = f(z)$ for every odd integer $2m$ (i.e., with reflections about half-integer $z$), what 1-dimensional space group would describe this system?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the infinite dihedral group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group. That group's generated by reflection and translation. For my example, a coordinate shift by $1/2$ along the $z$-axis would ensure that a generic $z \rightarrow -z$ reflection is part of the group.